# Visual Studio 2010 error "the application unable to start correcly (0xc000007b) for OpenGL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl

I am building an OpenGL Program in Visual Studio 2010 and my OS is windows 8 and when i run my program after it is successfully compiled. It gives me an error that the application unable to start correctly (0xc000007b) . Can anyone of you tell me the reason of this error and how it can be resolved?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["The application failed to initialize properly (0xc000007b)."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378616/the-application-failed-to-initialize-properly-0xc000007b)

Comment: The error code means that the executable image header isn't good (for whatever reason). So... compiled 64 bits and try to run under 32 bits, or defective harddisk would be two possibilities.

Comment: Mr. Damon do you know how can this problem be resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

you put "glut32.dll" and "glut.dll" two files in "C:\Windows\SysWOW64 ",
then your program will run successfully.