# MS Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, opencv

i searched stackoverflow and fixed the cannot find or open pdb files.
Everybody keeps saying that these are just warnings. but the code doesnt run
I tried everything i could find. 
I ran VS as administrator but it says

> 'hmd.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded
>   (source information stripped). 'hmd.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information
>   stripped). 'hmd.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll',
>   Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
>
> The program '[6156] hmd.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).

I know that symbols are loaded and i know that this question is asked several times but i didnt find any answers. i searched alot but these are the only errors that arise. and message window says exited with code (0xc000007b)

this is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    //open and read the image
    Mat img = imread("C:\\Users\\Hammad\\Desktop\\as.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    if (img.empty())
    {
        cout << "Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //change the color image to grayscale image
    cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    //equalize the histogram
    Mat img_hist_equalized;
    equalizeHist(img, img_hist_equalized);

    //create windows
    namedWindow("Original Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("Histogram Equalized", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    //show the image
    imshow("Original Image", img);
    imshow("Histogram Equalized",img_hist_equalized);

    waitKey(0); //wait for key press

    destroyAllWindows(); //destroy all open windows
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mistyped the error code in your edit. Please fix that.

Answer (score 1):

The key is the error code returned from your application: 0xc000007b. This usually indicates a mismatch between 32 and 64 bit components. Open your application in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find the modules that have mismatching bitness.

A more in-depth explanation of the error code can be found at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3379007/1889329).

A hacky 'solution' can be found at [this blog entry](http://msoos.wordpress.com/2010/09/11/0xc000007b-error-solution/).

Comment: i tried ur way. i made sure there isnt any mismatch in 32 or 64 bit components. still no cure :(

Comment: If you loaded up your application in Dependency Walker it will show you which modules have mismatching bitness. If this truly is a broken image header then Dependency Walker will show that as well.

Comment: *"Doesn't work"* is not an error description. What have you tried? What was the expected result? What was the actual result? Don't be lazy, be specific.

Comment: well i tried every way to sure sure that the program ran.its just a simple code using opencv. the last thing i tried is dependency walker.i made sure that every configuration, environment variables, the linker and additional directories are proper.  but this error doesnt vanish.