# OpenCV Visual Studio ntdll.dll

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I have trying to create a Project using OpenCV 2.4.10 on Visual Studio 2013, but I have had very little luck so far, owing to the following exceptions. Please suggest help. TIA.

```
'letstryitonemoretime.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Kndarp\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\letstryitonemoretime\Debug\letstryitonemoretime.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'letstryitonemoretime.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'letstryitonemoretime.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'letstryitonemoretime.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
First-chance exception at 0x77BC8F05 (ntdll.dll) in letstryitonemoretime.exe: 0xC000007B:  %hs is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support. Error status 0x.
Unhandled exception at 0x77BC8F05 (ntdll.dll) in letstryitonemoretime.exe: 0xC000007B:  %hs is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support. Error status 0x.
```

Comment: This looks like reinstalling Visual Studio might help.

Comment: @GPPK I tried that, It stills appears. I have only one project configured and I cannot configure any more projects.

Comment: hard to answer without the source

Comment: @Kornel if it helps - http://pastebin.com/V6wffJLT

Comment: Are you built opencv by yourself?

Comment: no, using binaries. should i build it myself?

Comment: @kndarp  Just guess - you've intermixed 64 bit libraries with 32 bit executable or vice versa. BTW, error can be found using search, for example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378616/the-application-failed-to-initialize-properly-0xc000007b

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error message because my program was trying to load a 32-bit DLL instead of the 64-bit DLL. You can see which DLLs your program is trying to load using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Do the following steps:

1. Open Dependency Walker
2. Open your executable (File->Open select your executable)
3. Make sure all your DLLs use the same CPU architecture. The middle pane lists all the DLL your program is using. The CPU column says if the DLL is 32-bit or 64-bit. They should all be the same.

In my case one of the DLLS was 32-bit instead of 64-bit because I had not added the 64-bit DLL to my environment path. I just copied the 64-bit DLL into the same folder as my program binary and the error went away.